# zul file is not rendered properly instead loaded as it is in Chrome

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, firefox, zk, zul

I'm using ZKOSS 6.5.3 framework with Eclipse and Maven.
In my app, I've written a simple zul file as follows:

**index.zul**

```
<?page title="Test Exam" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>

<zk xmlns:w="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client">
<window id="test_exam" title="Test Exam"
    apply="zkoss.controller.LoginComposer"
    style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border:1px solid red; height:500px; width:900px; display:block">

    <borderlayout id="main">
        <north>
            <vlayout style="padding:5px">
                <label id="testExamTitle" style="display:block">Exam Title</label>
                <label id="testExamDesc" style="display:block">Exam Description</label>
                <textbox style="border: 1px solid blue; display: inline-block;" tabindex="1" type="text"  width="100px" height="100px"></textbox>
            </vlayout>
        </north>
    </borderlayout>
</window>
</zk>
```

I've deployed this app on Tomcat 7(Eclipse). When I run the app & try to access this **zul** file in Chrome, instead of being rendered as a page with 2 Labels and 1 Textbox, it is being loaded as the HTML file itself as if I'm just opening the zul file in browser without deploying on server. It works perfectly on Firefox.
I've visited this [link](http://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-1250) whereas the similar problem is raised, but that also does not contain any solution.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: What if you remove the ContentType of the Page directive?

Comment: @chillworld Same issue

Comment: And if you remove the zk tag ?

Comment: @TheBakker, same issue.